# Error occured while trying to proxy to: <ip>:3000/api/v1/metadata, react app host in aws

Tags: node.js, reactjs, amazon-web-services, ubuntu

I have created react app with nodejs backend server. In my local machine (mac) this is working fine.

But when I host this app in aws ec2 server (ubuntu) , I'm getting this error when calling the backend apis.

`Error occured while trying to proxy to: <ip>:3000/api/v1/metadata`

I am using `http-proxy-middleware` to proxy requests for backend nodejs server.

`src/setupProxy.js`

```
const createProxyMiddleware = require('http-proxy-middleware')

module.exports = function (app) {
  app.use(
    '/api',
    createProxyMiddleware({
      target: 'http://127.0.0.1:5000',
      changeOrigin: true,
    })
  )
}
```

`inbound rules`
[image]

Comment: Can u do a curl to `http://127.0.0.1:5000` in ur ec2 instance and check if it is up or not?

Comment: @AritraChakraborty when I do `curl http://127.0.0.1:5000/api/v1/metadata` it gives me `curl: (7) Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1 port 5000: Connection refused`

Comment: Also the server logs: `Error occurred while trying to proxy request /api/v1/metadata from <ip>:3000 to http://localhost:5000/ (ECONNREFUSED) (https://nodejs.org/api/errors.html#errors_common_system_errors)`

Comment: Yeah i thought as much. how are u deploying the nodejs server? it seems that either 1) it's running in different port or 2) it's not running. post ur package.json or the deploy script however u are deploying

Comment: @AritraChakraborty Thanks for your reply. It seems like for a particular request my backend server app is getting crashed.`[0] [nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...`,  I will check the reason. Thanks for your time.